# Execute command line arguments within Coded UI Test Method

Tags: c#, command-line, coded-ui-tests

## Objective

Open command prompt and execute a command autonomously. I use Coded UI for test automation. This task can be completed either programmatically or via UI, it makes no difference.

---

## Problem

I am able to launch a command prompt window, but I am unable to execute a command, or pass any input to it for that matter. I have tried both examples below to execute a basic command in the command prompt, but with no success.

First attempt:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Arguments = "cd C:\\"
});
```

Second attempt:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
});
Keyboard.SendKeys("cd C:\\{Enter}");
```

---

## Question

Is there an effective way to execute commands in the command line using Coded UI? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why do this in CodedUI and not unit test or something else?  Why do you need to run this action via command line?

Comment: I have an application to test that can only be opened via cmd. I used a batch file